# Do any of these popular sites use the MVC pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, frameworks, design-patterns

I'm in the process of exploring Zend Framework, an MVC (Model View Controller) framework. I noticed that Zend's own site is using it (of course), but I was wondering if some of today's most popular sites:

- Amazon
- Facebook
- Twitter
- maybe Google?

do as well. I ask because I am curious if it is robust and manageable enough for huge sites like Amazon and Facebook. Does anyone know if they do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVC isn't a framework. *In the context of web programming*, is just a very rough division of labor:

Model is - usually, roughly - the code that handles data store

View is responsible for HTML generation etc

Controller is the part that translates incoming request to optional model changes and then hands off to some view.

I would be very surprised if the sites/companies you mentioned don't structure their code roughly like that, but as you can see it's only a very high-level structure and has more to do with maintainability / sane division of responsibilities than performance.

In any case, if you have to ask this kind of question, performance is NOT the first thing to worry about - relatively sane structure and readability of code is much, much more important, if only because the chances of getting enough users that serious scalability is an issue are low, while unmaintainable code *will* be an issue tomorrow - even if you have only one important user.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: I just wanted to add; a well-structured code base will help with performance, but mostly because a well-structured code base is easier to test, profile, modify & experiment with when performance issues turn up. If your code is a jumbled mess of functionality, it's much harder to figure out what's going on and change the bad stuff.